# Formula or polynomial algorithm for Combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem:
We have N - Urns with k1,k2,k3,k4 ... kn balls each other. Each ball is numbered with a number between 1 and N. Each urn has only balls with distinct numbers. How many combination can we make of N balls, one from each Urn in the condition that all balls from the combination must have distinct values.

Example:

1. Urn 1 : 1 2
2. Urn 2 : 1 2 3
3. Urn 3 : 1 3

Response is 3.

Justification:

There are 3 combinations:

1.   1 2 3 ( 1 from first Urn , 2 from second,...)
2.   2 1 3  
3.   2 3 1

Is there a polynomial algorthm or formula for that? Or is just a NP hard problem?

Thank you very much! 
Valentin

Comment: I forgot to mention. Each Urn cannot have more than N balls.

Comment: The usual name for a selection of that kind is a _system of distinct representatives_ or (more ambiguously) a _transversal_. Search for "Hall's marriage theorem" which gives necessary and sufficient conditions for an SDR to exist. Marshall Hall's extension of the theorem gives a lower bound for the number of SDRs. I think counting them is hard in general, but this page gives an algorithm to find one: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/marriage.shtml

Comment: Nice answer! Helps a lot. I did manage to find a solution or all solutions using recursive algorithms. But the complexity is Factorial. And my goal is only to count them to adjust a decision taking algorithm. Your answer is a good step forward as now I know what to search next.